# NSet containsObject is giving unpredictable results

Tags: objective-c, nsset

In my following code [NSSet containsObject] is giving unpredictable results. I find out that Cell3 object with value row,col (2,2) gets added twice thorough my while loop. **However if I set breakpoint inside the method isEqual on the line of if condition then (2,2) does not get added twice.**

Is this issue related to code optimizations. When I use to work in C++ long time back, I saw these kinds of issues in debug vs release mode. If you set breakpoints then the issue does not happen but if no breakpoint then the issue happens. I have never seen this kind of issue in XCode. I am using XCode version 9.2(9C40b)

```
@interface Cell3 : NSObject

@property(assign) NSInteger row;
@property(assign) NSInteger col;

-(instancetype) initWithRow:(NSInteger)row col:(NSInteger)col;
@end


@implementation Cell3

-(instancetype) initWithRow:(NSInteger)row col:(NSInteger)col
{
    self = [super init];
    if(self)
    {
        self.row = row;
        self.col = col;
    }
    return self;
}

- (BOOL)isEqual:(Cell3*)object
{
    if(self.row == object.row && self.col == object.col)
        return YES;
    else
        return NO;
}

@end


int NSSetTest()
{
    NSMutableSet *uniqueCells = [[NSMutableSet alloc]init];

    int a = 0;

    int b[9][2] = { {0,0}, {1,0}, {2,0}, {3,0}, {3,1}, {3,2}, {2,2}, {2,3}, {2,2} };

    while(a < 9)
    {
        Cell3 *cell = [[Cell3 alloc] initWithRow:b[a][0] col:b[a][1]];

        if(![uniqueCells containsObject:cell])
        {
            [uniqueCells addObject:cell];
        }
        a++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Also you do realize that your `containsObject` test is unnecessary? The whole point of a set is that an object won’t appear twice

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that. Actually what I posted here was a version of the code which shows the problem. In real, I am doing something else by checking for containsObject which does not give me the right behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your Cell3 class lacks an appropriate `hash` implementation. See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1418859-hash

Comment: Yes I saw that but I have nothing to implement in the hash method. The documentation states that "Returns an integer that can be used as a table address in a hash table structure" Why do you want me to change the implementation of the super class defined method? Also why this problem does not happen when I set the the breakpoint in isEqual method?

Comment: “Why do you want me to change the implementation of the super class defined method” Because it’s wrong. It will put two equal Cell3 objects into different buckets, but they must go into the same bucket or set functionality will break (as has in fact happened).